# Using Common Table Expression and Outer queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

In following query I'm use both Common Table Expression and Outer queries. Apparently both looks same to me.

*If I summarize my requirement, I have employees in `SalaryTrans` table and I want to find out amounts to be recovered from their salaries monthly. Table `Rcovery` contains all recovery data.  Table `Instalment` contains all previously paid amounts so I want to sum all paid amounts and then it is deducted from total amount to calculate `balance` amount.*

So what I'm doing here is in `CTE`, I'm getting two numeric fields called `recovered_amount` and `total_amount`. In second query I'm checking whether `recovered_amount` is not null and if it's not null I'm calculating the `balance`.

In outer query I have a criteria to filter out less than 0 balances from the result.

```
WITH CTE (employee_id, RID, instalment, reference, recovered_amount, total_amount) AS  
         (SELECT SalaryTrans.employee_id, Recovery.RID, Recovery.amount / Recovery.duration AS instalment, 
          SalaryTrans.reference, SUM(Instalment.recovered_amount) AS recovered_amount,       Recovery.amount AS total_amount
          FROM Recovery INNER JOIN
                        SalaryTrans ON Recovery.emp_id = SalaryTrans.employee_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                        Instalment ON Recovery.RID = Instalment.recovery_id
          GROUP BY SalaryTrans.employee_id, SalaryTrans.reference, Recovery.RID, Recovery.amount / Recovery.duration, Recovery.amount)


SELECT RID, Balance, reference  FROM 
      (SELECT RID, 
       "Balance" = CASE WHEN recovered_amount !=NULL 
                   THEN total_amount-recovered_amount 
                   ELSE total_amount END , 
       reference FROM CTE) AS Result 
WHERE Balance >0
```

This query gives intended output. But I want to know Can I do whole thing using CTE or simply should I use outer queries in this case. Also any idea to make it look better?

Could you please review this and give your feedback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Common table expressions

In general, common table expressions are an excellent way to build complex queries.  For databases that support CTEs, I fully recommend using them in preference to correlated subqueries, since chaining is much more readable than nesting.  I would suggest that you rewrite the nested `Result` subquery as a CTE as well, if there weren't a completely superior approach (see **Rewrite** below).

If you're going to use CTEs, name them properly.  `CTE` is just about the least informative name possible for a CTE.

### Schema

You have some inconsistencies in the schema.  For example, `Recovery` has an `emp_id` column, but `SalaryTrans` has an `employee_id` column.  You should also name the columns with consistent capitalization.

### Nitpicks

Looking inside your CTE, I see a few minor problems.  I won't go into too much detail, since the whole query should be rewritten anyway.

I'm going to make a guess that the `Recovery` table has `RID` as its primary key, and that the `SalaryTrans` table has `reference` as its primary key.  (It would be nice to include such information about the schema when asking questions — it makes reviews easier to write.)  Since `Recovery.amount / Recovery.duration AS instalment` is never used in the main query, there is no point to computing it in the CTE.  Also, it would be redundant to `GROUP BY Recovery.amount / Recovery.duration`, since there would never be two different values of `Recovery.amount / Recovery.duration` for any given `RID`.  (The only effect it has would be to trigger a division-by-zero error if `duration` is zero, and I doubt that that was intentional.)

Your CTE should mention the columns, tables, and `GROUP BY` columns in a logical and consistent order.

Part of the reason you have so many `GROUP BY` columns is that you are joining `SalaryTrans` prematurely.

### Rewrite

The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is problematic.  Assuming that the `Instalment` table is sanely designed such that the `recovered_amount` column is non-nullable, the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` introduces a needless null-handling complication.  Rather than joining the `Recovery` and `Instalment` tables side-by-side, you want to combine them vertically.

```
WITH RecoveryEntries AS (
    SELECT RID, emp_id, amount
        FROM Recovery
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Recovery.RID, Recovery.emp_id, -Instalment.recovered_amount
        FROM Recovery
            INNER JOIN Instalment
                ON Recovery.RID = Instalment.recovery_id
), NetRecovery AS (
    SELECT RID, emp_id, SUM(amount) AS Balance
        FROM RecoveryEntries
        GROUP BY RID, emp_id
)
SELECT NetRecovery.RID, NetRecovery.Balance, SalaryTrans.reference
    FROM NetRecovery
        INNER JOIN SalaryTrans
            ON NetRecovery.emp_id = SalaryTrans.employee_id
    WHERE NetRecovery.Balance > 0
```

Comment: Nice review, Thank you very much!. One thing to clarify... I need `Recovery.amount / Recovery.duration AS instalment` too in the final result. So what's the best way to add this?

Comment: To get `instalment`, if I rejoin `Recovery` table in the final `SELECT...` , I can get the required output. Is it ok?

Comment: We've covered all three ways: 1) `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, as in your original question; 2) Treat `instalment` just like `Recovery.emp_id`; 3) Rejoin `Recovery`. Each has advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 2):

I find the query rather difficult to read due to your indentation style.  For your benefit and for the benefit of other reviewers, I've reformatted your query, changing only the whitespace:

```
WITH CTE (employee_id, RID, instalment, reference, recovered_amount, total_amount) AS (
    SELECT SalaryTrans.employee_id
         , Recovery.RID
         , Recovery.amount / Recovery.duration AS instalment
         , SalaryTrans.reference
         , SUM(Instalment.recovered_amount) AS recovered_amount
         , Recovery.amount AS total_amount
        FROM Recovery
            INNER JOIN SalaryTrans
                ON Recovery.emp_id = SalaryTrans.employee_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Instalment
                ON Recovery.RID = Instalment.recovery_id
        GROUP BY SalaryTrans.employee_id
               , SalaryTrans.reference
               , Recovery.RID
               , Recovery.amount / Recovery.duration
               , Recovery.amount
)
SELECT RID, Balance, reference
    FROM (
            SELECT RID
                 , "Balance" = CASE
                      WHEN recovered_amount != NULL THEN total_amount - recovered_amount 
                      ELSE total_amount
                   END
                 , reference
                FROM CTE
        ) AS Result 
    WHERE Balance > 0
```

In particular, note:

1. For anything other than a trivial `SELECT`, use a separate line for each column being selected.  (My use of leading commas may be controversial.  I find that it helps prevent silly mistakes when editing the query to add and remove columns.)
2. The indentation matches the clauses of each expression.  For example,

   - The big-picture structure is `WITH` *(CTEs)* `SELECT` *(something)*.

     - Within the CTE, `SELECT` takes a `FROM` clause and a `GROUP BY` clause.

       - The `FROM` clause consists of two `JOIN`s.
     - The main `SELECT` has a `FROM` clause and a `WHERE` clause.

       - Within the `CASE`, make it more obvious that the `THEN` is associated with `WHEN`.
3. Use a space on each side of binary operators such as `!=`, `-`, and `>`.